# Using nested For Each and If to return a node value from a different child node

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am trying to extract the zipcode when 'CreditCard' is one of the payment methods.  There are often multiple payment methods, i.e. Credit Card & Cash; Credit Card & Gift Card; etc.  A credit card is not necessarily the first payment, but there is never a case where more than one Credit Card is allowed.  I want to loop through all the payment types and when the payment type value is 'CreditCard', then retrieve the zip code.  If no Credit Cards are used, the value should be null.

Based on my initial research, it looks like I need a nested For-Each, but not necessarily an IF.  I have found plenty of articles that explain nested for-each statements and articles that show simple if statements.  I have not found any clear articles that show retrieving from different node levels with these combined statements.  Here's my pseudocode for this one line:

> IF... purchases/purchase/payments/payment/type = 'CreditCard'
>   THEN value of...  purchases/purchase/payments/payment/address/zipcode

The various version I've tried have not failed in the SSIS package but have not retrieved results.

XML sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<exportbatch xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<purchases>
    <purchase>
        <posRef>987654321</posRef>
        <locationRef>1234</locationRef>
        <totalamount>99.9900</totalamount>
        <payments>
            <payment>
                <amount>50.0000</amount>
                <description>Gift Card x-8765</description>
                <type>GiftCard</type>
            </payment>
            <payment>
                <amount>19.5200</amount>
                <description>some credit card brand x-8765</description>
                <brand>some credit card brand</brand>
                <type>CreditCard</type>
                <address>
                    <zipcode>65432</zipcode>
                </address>
            </payment>
        </payments>
    </purchase>
</purchases>
</exportbatch>
```

XSLT example:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="exportbatch">
    <purchases>
    <xsl:for-each select="purchases/purchase">
        <purchase>
            <posRef><xsl:value-of select="posRef"/></posRef>
            <LocationId><xsl:value-of select="locationRef"/></LocationId>
            <TotalAmount><xsl:value-of select="totalamount"/></TotalAmount>
            <xsl:for-each select="payments/payment/type">
                <xsl:if test="'CreditCard'">
                    <PaymentZipCode><xsl:value-of select="address/zipcode"/></PaymentZipCode>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </purchase>
    </xsl:for-each>
    </purchases>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Alternate XSLT example:

```
    <xsl:for-each select="payments/payment">
        <xsl:if test="@type='CreditCard'">
            <PaymentZipCode><xsl:value-of select="address/zipcode"/></PaymentZipCode>
        </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

Comment: Is the address with the zip code always in the payment whose type is CreditCard?

Comment: Yes, zip code is always associated with CreditCard.

Comment: You use `xsl:for-each select="purchases/order"`, but there is no `order` element; only `purchase`. Is this a typo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could do:

```
<xsl:template match="exportbatch">
    <purchases>
        <xsl:for-each select="purchases/purchase">
            <purchase>
                <posRef><xsl:value-of select="posRef"/></posRef>
                <LocationId><xsl:value-of select="locationRef"/></LocationId>
                <TotalAmount><xsl:value-of select="totalamount"/></TotalAmount>
                <xsl:variable name="cc" select="payments/payment[type='CreditCard']" />
                <xsl:if test="$cc">
                    <PaymentZipCode><xsl:value-of select="$cc/address/zipcode"/></PaymentZipCode>
                </xsl:if>
            </purchase>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </purchases>
</xsl:template>
```

This tests if a `payment` whose type is `CreditCard` exists - and if it does, it retrieves the zip code from there.

Alternatively, you could do:

```
<xsl:template match="exportbatch">
    <purchases>
        <xsl:for-each select="purchases/purchase">
            <purchase>
                <posRef><xsl:value-of select="posRef"/></posRef>
                <LocationId><xsl:value-of select="locationRef"/></LocationId>
                <TotalAmount><xsl:value-of select="totalamount"/></TotalAmount>
                <xsl:if test="payments/payment[type='CreditCard']">
                    <PaymentZipCode><xsl:value-of select="payments/payment/address/zipcode"/></PaymentZipCode>
                </xsl:if>
            </purchase>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </purchases>
</xsl:template>
```

This does the same test, and if it passes it retrieves the first zip code it can find.